# Sqlite - Count Unique Values based on Column

Tags: c++, mysql, sqlite

I've got a table like this (C, Sqlite). And I want to count the number of **unique** ports each IP address contacts.

```
id | ip_src       | ip_dst | port 
-----------------------------------
1  | 192.168.45.3 | ...    | 442
2  | 132.43.13.4  | ...    | 42
3  | 111.5.34.3   | ...    | 80
4  | 54.2.2.1     | ...    | 8322
5  | 54.2.2.1     | ...    | 8322
6  | 192.168.45.3 | ...    | 80
7  | 192.168.45.3 | ...    | 23
```

The result of the query should ideally look something like this:

```
192.168.45.3 = 3
132.43.13.4 = 1
111.5.34.3 = 1
54.2.2.1 = 1
```

What would the query look like for this?

I've tried:

```
SELECT src_ip, COUNT(DISTINCT port) FROM synpackets;
```

But it's not giving out the correct result, it seems to be only counting the first IP address.

Comment: The point of SO is not to write your code for you - the point is to solve the problems in the code you have written.  So, try something and if it doesn't work, you can ask for help on fixing the issues in your submission.

Comment: This is not a coding service. Post the code for what you have tried so far.

Comment: What result are you getting? You might need to put a group by on the end of your query: GROUP BY src_ip.

Comment: It's only giving me the count for one IP address and it's counting both the source and destination IP fields it seems

Comment: So what happens if you put the group by clause on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to get the unique ports first. Therefore, you have to nest two select statements like this:

```
SELECT T.ip_src AS ip_src, 
Count(T.ports) AS numberPorts 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ip_src, ports FROM <TABLE>) AS T 
GROUP BY T.ip_src;
```

In the inner select statement the results are all unique ip_src and ports pairs. Using this recordset we then can count the ports. Mind the `GROUP BY`. 
Otherwise we would not get the unique port count.

Comment: What are the "T." bits about and where you say "AS T GROUP" though?

Comment: The `T.` refers to the "new" name of the inner SELECT statement. `AS T` renames the inner SELECT statement to T. It possibly works without the renaming, but with bigger and multiple nested statements it's a bit more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

SELECT src_ip, COUNT(*) FROM synpackets group by src_ip, port;

Comment: Grouping by `port` will give a distinct count *per* port; grouping by `src_ip` should be sufficient.  Although they'll probably need `COUNT(DISTINCT port)` as well, assuming SQLite supports that.

Comment: That is true but that query would give results given as an example, 
192.168.45.3 = 3
132.43.13.4 = 1
111.5.34.3 = 1
54.2.2.1 = 1